# How to disable trimming input in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using `ag-grid 25.0.0 enterprise` on react 16
I want to disable the trimming feature which is enabled by default in text `filter(agTextColumnFilter)`.

I tried by adding the `filterParams:{trimInput: false}` explicitly but still it keeps trimming. I've added `debounceMs` as well as a work around but it would be good if I can disable this feature.

Comment: Check [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zIbWaFhWJgRbQ8nn?open=index.jsx) , its working. Official doc example https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-text/

Comment: Yes, in this example it's working fine. But somehow in mine it doesn't even after setting it false explicitly. I'll check whether some other filter param is overwriting this one. Thanks for your response.